# Changing Foreground for IsMouseOver anf IsPressed is not working in custom style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

No matter what I try I can't set get the trigger `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed` to change the `Foreground`.
I have been trying to alter it in the `Button` itself.

```
<Button (STUFF HERE)>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF373737"/>
                    </Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4D4D4E"/>
                    </Trigger>
</Button>
```

I have been trying to look it up, but I am pretty amateur with XAML.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It's not necessary to put stuff like C#, WPF and .NET in your question's title or body as that's what the groovy _tags_ are for.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a style where you put the `Triggers`. Add this style to any resource dictionary in scope, e.g. the `Window.Resources` or the application resources if you want to reuse it across the application. If you omit the `x:Key`, you make it *implicit* and therefore apply to all `Button`s in scope.

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF373737"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4D4D4E"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then reference that style in the `Button`.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" .../>
```

Alternatively, you could also directly assign the style to the `Button` if it is the only one.

```
<Button Content="Styled">
   <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF373737"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4D4D4E"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Note that while this works for the `Foreground` property, it does not for properties like `Background` as they are defined in the `ControlTemplate` triggers which take precedence over a style. In order change those, you have to copy and adapt the `Button` `ControlTemplate`.

---

Update for your comment. Maybe you understand the `Foreground` property wrong. It is used for the text color of the content, not the color of the button itself. The *"blue-ish" tint* is determined by the `Background` property and as stated above, you have to edit the `ControlTemplate` for that.

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FF373737"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FF4D4D4E"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Though I am not getting any errors, It wont apply to the button (both of them) and uses the default blue-ish mouse over effect

Comment: @Bandit Ok, there might be a misunderstanding here. The `Foreground` property applies to the **text color**. The `Background` property determines the background of the button (the blue-ish) effect. Did you mean that?

Comment: No, i meant foreground like the text color

Answer (score 0):

here the general layout for styling controls:

```
<Button Content="OK">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Style.Triggers >
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF373737"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4D4D4E"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

If you want to reuse the style, then save it to a resourcedictionary as a named style and you can refer to it on your controls